# using zend view object as persistent storage

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, view

so I was looking at this tutorial:

http://devzone.zend.com/article/3412

and it says that

"Within Zend Framework's MVC, in most cases placeholders do not make sense; since the same view object is utilized between all controllers and the layout by default, you can simply utilize view variables as a persistent storage mechanism."

can someone explain to me ho this 'persistent storage mechanism' work? I tried going to a view file, setting $this->test = 'something', and then go to another view file and echo $this->test

but nothing came up....

Comment: Can you be more explicit, perhaps show some code? Was this for a single request where one view script included the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call the view scripts within the same request and the sequence is correct then your test will work.

```
view-script1.phtml
<h3>Test one</h3>
<p>nothing</p><?php $this->test = 'something'; ?>

view-script2.phtml
<h3>Test two</h3>
<p><?php echo $this->test; ?></p>
```

If you don't see the two `<h3>` titles in the correct sequence or one is missing then you are not calling the view scripts correctly.

Furthermore the best example for the persistent storage are the controllers. If you forward to other actions or even controllers you can pass data through them

```
controller1/actionOne
$this->view->test = 'something';

controller2/actionTwo
$this->view->test .= ' more';

in your viewscript
echo $this->test;  // will print "something more"
```

Answer (score 0):

persistence storage is nothing more then static function registry used by Zend_View_Helper_Placeholder_Registry class , since it is a static function it can be shared with many objects hence called persistence in context of view helpers which are sub-classes of this placeholder  .